# Sum if based on value in another column

Tags: sql, sum

In the below code, I want the `AdminDuration` and `BreakDuration` to sum based on what the value of `UserID` is. At the moment I can't figure it out, and it sums the values of all `Duration`s with `ReasonCode` 7. As a result every `UserId` has the same `Duration` (not what I want!).

```
Select SkillTargetID AS UserID,
(SELECT sum(Duration) 
   from [t_Agent_Event_Detail] 
   where ReasonCode = 7
   and DateTime > convert(DATETIME, '2013-01-31 08:00', 21)) as AdminDuration,
(SELECT sum(Duration) 
   from [t_Agent_Event_Detail] 
   where ReasonCode = 6
   and DateTime > convert(DATETIME, '2013-01-31 08:00', 21) 
   and SkillTargetID = [t_Agent_Event_Detail].SkillTargetID) as BreakDuration 
from [t_Agent_Event_Detail]
GROUP BY SkillTargetID
```

Answer (score 18):

If I understand you correctly, it should be:

```
SELECT SkillTargetID AS UserID,
       sum(CASE WHEN ReasonCode = 7 THEN Duration ELSE 0 END) as AdminDuration,
       sum(CASE WHEN ReasonCode = 6 THEN Duration ELSE 0 END) as BreakDuration
FROM [t_Agent_Event_Detail]
WHERE DateTime > convert(DATETIME, '2013-01-31 08:00', 21)
GROUP BY SkillTargetID
```